# Cordova application targetting S5 and Moto E

Tags: css, cordova

I have an application which runs only in portrait mode. I want to load css depending upon screen sizes for S5 and smaller one for Moto E.

homeScreenStyle and Configurecss for S5
homeScreenStyleiPhone and iphoneConfigure for Moto E

Device  Pixel Width Pixel Height CSS Pixel Ratio    Device-Width    Device-Height

Moto E      960 540 2   480 270

Galaxy S5   1920    1080    3   640 360

I tried different variations for css but it is not working,

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height">

<link  media="screen and (max-device-width: 350px)" href="assets/css/homeScreenStyleiphone.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link  media="screen and (min-device-width:360px)" href="assets/css/homeScreenStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">



<link   media="screen and (max-device-width: 350px)" href="assets/newcss/iphoneconfigure.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link   media="screen and (min-device-width:360px)" href="assets/newcss/configure.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Please help. I am unable to figure out exact width.

Comment: I tried to load depending upon height but it is not loading different css.

Answer (score 0):

In your css file use width and height of element in percentage value, For example

```
div.container
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
}
```

It will automatically fit the element according to device width, No need of more css files

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know why you only target for 2 mobile phones?  would like to share my experience with you.

First of all, I target on any desktop & mobile browsers plus Android phones plus iphones.

For the screen available width and height, I get it using JavaScript, you may get these js by google windowHeight and windowWidth.

For the css, I only use 1 css, but all the numbers in the css are set dynamically with a ratio with respect to the screen width or height.  e.g. font-size = windowHeight / 20

then the looking seen by the users should be similar on different phones or browsers